# What's the URL to download a crx1 Chrome Extension offline?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm familiar with this:
https://clients2.google.com/service/update2/crx?response=redirect&prodversion=[prodversion]&x=id%3D[extensionid]%26uc

But I'd like to download the extension for an older, specific version of Chrome, that only supports CRX1 extensions.

Comment: The web store doesn't have older versions. It'll probably do in the future, see https://crbug.com/899396#c6

Comment: URL for Manifest Changes: https://developer.chrome.com/apps/manifest/version

Comment: URL Info to download a crx: https://blog.httpwatch.com/2017/11/15/installing-a-chrome-extension-without-an-internet-connection/

Comment: CRX Viewer: https://github.com/Rob--W/crxviewer  This can set different OS versions and CRX versions (2 vs 3) but not CRX1.

Comment: 1) CRX version is not related to the extension's version. 2) CRX1 support was removed long time ago from Chrome so the web store shouldn't have any of those lying around.